# merge two foreach in one layout

Tags: php

i got two arrays.

from results i want to make a table with `foreach`

but i dont know how to make it work in one table row..

this is what i got

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($appky as $appka) : ?>
<tr class="counter_apps" height="20px"  >
<td width="40%"><?php echo $appka->name; ?></td>
<td width="20%"><?php echo $appka->all_items;?></td>
<td width="20%"><?php echo $appka->published; ?></td>
<td width="20%"><?php echo $appka->unpublished; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
</table>

<table>
<?php foreach ($applications as $application) : ?>
<tr><td><?php echo $application->name; ?></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>  
</table>
```

so what i want is simply add to the first table another column with `$application->name;`

what i'm missing here??
thanks

Comment: have you tried with inner foreach?

Comment: Give us an example of both of the 2 arrays you are processing

Comment: Give us an example of the 2 array i.e the output of a `print_r()` on each, if only to stop people **guessing**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your two arrays aren't necessarily in order - If you have some data that matches between your `$appka` and `$application` you can try something like this below:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($appky as $appka) : ?>
<tr class="counter_apps" height="20px"  >
<td width="40%"><?php echo $appka->name; ?></td>
<td width="20%"><?php echo $appka->all_items;?></td>
<td width="20%"><?php echo $appka->published; ?></td>
<td width="20%"><?php echo $appka->unpublished; ?></td>
  <?php foreach ($applications as $application) : ?>
    <?php if ($appka->id == $application->id) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $application->name; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?> 
</tr>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
</table>
```

Otherwise you wont be able to spit out the correct application name.  The above solution uses an `id` field, but you probably hove something else you can match on.

Comment: Do you see any reference to `$appka->id` OR `$application->id` in the question? Ask for more information, dont just guess.

Comment: No, but there were three possibilities to his answer: A- the arrays are in order with each other allowing you to use the index based approach, B- each array has a matching identifier allowing you to use my approach, C- there is no way to match the application name with the initial array in the current state. Since the index based method was already suggested I felt it helpful to provide my idea.  My post was marked as the answer I will take it that I helped the OP.  I don't appreciate your argumentative and rhetorical comment. There are more positive ways to go about suggesting things.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
<?php 
$count = count($appky);
for($i=0; $i< $count; $i++) { ?>
    <tr class="counter_apps" height="20px"  >
    <td width="40%"><?php echo $appky[$i]->name; ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $appky[$i]->all_items;?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $appky[$i]->published; ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $appky[$i]->unpublished; ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $applications[$i]->name; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: i've not downvoted, but there is a risk that the size of `$applications` will be not equal of the size of `$appky`

Comment: How can you possible know for sure that `$appka[1]` and `$application[1]` are in any way directly related from the information provided by the questioner?

Comment: @HalayemAnis yes, you are right, but I considered from the question example the their size is equal. `isset($applications[$i]) ? $applications[$i]->name : '' ;` is good solution.

Comment: @RiggsFolly you should look at question code example.

Comment: your both solutions works for me.. i choose the first one as @Halayem Anis suggest right name is the same..

Answer (score 0):

use `for` instead of `foreach`

```
<table>
<?php for($i=0 ; $i<count($appky) ; $i++ ) { ?>
    <tr class="counter_apps" height="20px"  >
    <td width="40%"><?php echo $appka[$i]->name; ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $appka[$i]->all_items;?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $appka[$i]->published; ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo $appka[$i]->unpublished; ?></td>
    <td width="20%"><?php echo isset($applications[$i]) ? $applications[$i]->name : '' ; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Not sure why someone would down vote and not comment, this method works fine. +1

Comment: How can you possible know for sure that `$appka[1]` and `$application[1]` are in any way directly related from the information provided by the questioner?

Comment: Very true @RiggsFolly, this did work in my case but I can see your point. Maybe the OP needs to add more detail on the structure of each array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's already a poor design, but the questionnaire hasn't mentioned that these arrays must be linked in special way. i've simply guessed his intention... next time i'll be more careful. thanks